# WIFI Celular and VPN on windows. Default route problems

Tags: windows, networking, routes

I have a windows 11 PC with WiFi and a cellular modem. Due to specifics not that important I must use the cellular modem to connect through VPN to my company network and use WiFi to connect to every other network including the internet. Both connections are up at the same time. I have removed the default metrics on both adapters IPv4 and specified 10 for WiFI and 200 for Cell.

## IPv4 Route Table

## Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.41     20
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.1.122.65      10.1.122.96    286
10.1.122.64  255.255.255.192         On-link       10.1.122.96    286
10.1.122.96  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.122.96    286
10.1.122.127  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.122.96    286
127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
172.17.1.1  255.255.255.255      10.1.122.65      10.1.122.96     31
172.17.192.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.17.192.1    271
172.17.192.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.192.1    271
172.17.207.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.192.1    271
172.17.208.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.17.208.1    271
172.17.208.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.208.1    271
172.17.223.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.208.1    271
172.28.48.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.28.48.1   5256
172.28.48.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.48.1   5256
172.28.63.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.48.1   5256
192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.41    266
192.168.1.41  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.41    266
192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.41    266
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.17.208.1    271
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.41    266
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.17.192.1    271
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.122.96    286
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.28.48.1   5256
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.208.1    271
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.41    266
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.192.1    271
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.122.96    286
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.48.1   5256

## Persistent Routes:
Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
172.17.1.1  255.255.255.255      10.1.122.65       1

I have specified my VPN remote party through a route in windows to use the cellular network(the 172.17.1.1 persistent route) and all works fine until i connect the VPN. The default route in that moment changes to the VPN connection as 'On-Link' and the specified default route by me on WiFi get a 4000+ metric.

Routing table after VPN connected

## IPv4 Route Table

## Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.41   4245
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.1.122.65      10.1.122.96   4511
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link     10.199.199.41    101
10.1.122.64  255.255.255.192         On-link       10.1.122.96   4511
10.1.122.96  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.122.96   4511
10.1.122.127  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.122.96   4511
10.199.199.41  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.199.199.41    356
127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
172.17.1.1  255.255.255.255      10.1.122.65      10.1.122.96   4256
172.17.192.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.17.192.1   4496
172.17.192.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.192.1   4496
172.17.207.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.192.1   4496
172.17.208.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.17.208.1   4496
172.17.208.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.208.1   4496
172.17.223.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.208.1   4496
172.28.48.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.28.48.1   9481
172.28.48.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.48.1   9481
172.28.63.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.48.1   9481
172.30.112.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.30.112.1   5256
172.30.112.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.30.112.1   5256
172.30.127.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.30.112.1   5256
192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.41   4491
192.168.1.41  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.41   4491
192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.41   4491
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.17.208.1   4496
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.41   4491
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.17.192.1   4496
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.122.96   4511
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.28.48.1   9481
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.199.199.41    101
224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.30.112.1   5256
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.208.1   4496
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.41   4491
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.17.192.1   4496
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.122.96   4511
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.28.48.1   9481
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.199.199.41    356
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.30.112.1   5256

## Persistent Routes:
Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
172.17.1.1  255.255.255.255      10.1.122.65       1

I am posting my entire IPv4 routing table if there is any relevant information in there so sorry if not and that is too long.

Even if I remove and add the default route with a lower metric for the WiFi compared to the VPN it says OK but the result is still the same.

Output is abbreviated

## C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print 0.0.0.0
IPv4 Route Table

## Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.41   4245
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.1.122.65      10.1.122.96   4511
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link     10.199.199.26    101

Persistent Routes:
None

C:\WINDOWS\system32>route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
OK!

## C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print 0.0.0.0

## IPv4 Route Table

## Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.1.122.65      10.1.122.96   4511
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link     10.199.199.26    101

Persistent Routes:
None

C:\WINDOWS\system32>route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 metric 1
OK!

## C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print 0.0.0.0
IPv4 Route Table

## Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.1.122.65      10.1.122.96   4511
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link     10.199.199.26    101
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.41   4236

Persistent Routes:
None

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend on this.